# C++ error in malloc

Tags: c++

I am new to C/C++ and trying to test my understanding of pointers. For this I created the following simple program to create an integer array to store 10 numbers and print it out.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
// #include <cstdint> 
int main(){
    int numberOfItems = 10;
    int *array;
    // int *array = malloc((int*)numberOfItems*sizeof(int));
    array = malloc((int*)numberOfItems*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++){
        *array = i;
        array++;
        i++;
    }
    std::cout<<"The size of the array is : "<<sizeof(array)<<std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++){
        std::cout<<*array<<std::endl;
        array++;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I ran the program using the command `g++ main.cpp`.
But it gives me the following error:

> main.cpp:8:47: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘long unsigned int’ to binary ‘operator*’
>         array = malloc((int*)numberOfItems*sizeof(int));

**Tried and Failed**
I tried to change the int to `uint64_t` but still it gave me similar kind of error.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` with C++ in the first place?

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in c++.  Use `new`, or better yet use smart pointers.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `malloc`.  The error is with `(int*)numberOfItems` `*` `sizeof(int)`.  That is a pointer type multiplied by an integral type.  C++ recognizes no such thing.

Comment: `array = malloc((int*)numberOfItems*sizeof(int));` --> `array = (int*)malloc(numberOfItems*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Stop doing C/C++. It's the worst of both worlds. Learn C **and** C++ the right way, as *separate* languages.

Comment: ...or just learn one of these. It's enough in many cases.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector `?

Comment: Yes. Remember you are allocating memory for a pointer to an array of int values. Not an array of int pointers.

Comment: You may also wish to note that `sizeof(array)` is not going to give you the amount of space you mallocced, it will return the size of a single int pointer, size that is what you asked for the size of.   The `sizeof` operator computes its value at compile time, and has nothing to do with how much space you might allocate

Comment: I hate to say it but you're _mislearning_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through your code step by step:

```
int *array;
array = malloc((int*)numberOfItems*sizeof(int));
```

Here you have two problems:

1. `malloc` is `C`, not `C++`. Yes, `malloc` is supported in `C++`, but for backwawrds compatibility with legacy code. Do not use it.
2. You cast `numberOfItems` to a *pointer*, then multiply the *pointer* with an *integer*. That's undefined behavior. Your compiler might even do the right thing here, but you cannot know and you cannot trust any result you're getting.

Let's continue:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++){
    *array = i;
    array++;
    i++;
}
```

The `for` declaration looks fine. You initialize an integer `i` to `0`, and you increment it using the `++` operator as long as it is smaller than `numberOfItems`, that's good. **But**:

1. You increment `i` **again** inside your loop. That means you actually increment `i` by 2, so `i` goes `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10`, and your loop is only executed 5 times.
2. You increment your `array` pointer. While technically perfectly valid code, this will bite you further down.
3. So you write the values 0, 2, 4, 6 and 8 into memory at the initial location of your `array` pointer, and `1*sizeof(int)`, `2*sizeof(int)`, `3*sizeof(int)`, `4*sizeof(int)` bytes further down each.

Next problem:

```
std::cout<<"The size of the array is : "<<sizeof(array)<<std::endl;
```

This will not print what you meant it to print. `array` is a pointer type, so `sizeof(array)` will return the size of a *pointer*, which is probably either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the bitnes of your application/OS.

And last but not least your last loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++){
    std::cout<<*array<<std::endl;
    array++;
    i++;
}
```

1. You do the same thing with `i` as in your first loop. This time, this saves your neck, because...
2. ...since you incremented the pointer `array` already in your first loop, you're now continuing at `5*sizeof(int)` bytes further down in the memory. You're therefore not printing the values you set in the first loop (which was probably your intention), but uninitialized values that reside in the second half of the memory originally allocated at `array`.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the fact that your syntax is incorrect in the following line.

```
array = malloc((int*)numberOfItems*sizeof(int));
```

The right syntax would be as follows:

```
array = (int*) malloc(numberOfItems*sizeof(int));
```

You need to typecast the return value of `malloc` as it returns a `(void *)` pointer. So, you need to specify what type of data you would be pointing when you access the memory.

Comment: You should not use `malloc ` in C++ code. Confusion arises on the choice of  `delete` or `free.`

Comment: @EdHeal: you are right when it comes to programming practices. But for a general beginner program it might not hurt that much. ;)

Comment: @EdHeal: There is no choice.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yes there is 1) malloc/free compared with new/delete might be using a different system to do the accounting of memory allocated. 2) delete calls the destructors/free does not.